# State level unemployment in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a newbie question. I want to plot the state level unemployment in the US map. There have been profound discussions here and elsewhere about how to plot county level unemployment and the issues associated with it. The code looks intimidating to me. Is there a simple code out there which takes two columns, a state code and a factor variable  indicating numeric intervals and yields a colored US map(based on the factor variable). A supplementary question  is that if I need to go a little further and create  similar plot but with unemployment rate in major cities of US how do I modify the code.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd start with linking to the code you have found and can't get to work or understand. Do you have your hands on the unemployment data you need to plot? This package on CRAN seems like it would be relevant to what you need to do: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UScensus2000/index.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a quick piece of code with comments explaining each step. Let me know if you have questions

```
# load libraries
library(XML);
library(ggplot2);
library(maps);
library(plyr);

# read the data from the bls website with correct column formats
unemp = readHTMLTable('http://www.bls.gov/web/laus/laumstrk.htm',
  colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'numeric'))[[2]];

# rename columns and convert region to lowercase
names(unemp) = c('rank', 'region', 'rate');
unemp$region  = tolower(unemp$region);

# get us state map data and merge with unemp
us_state_map = map_data('state');
map_data = merge(unemp, us_state_map, by = 'region'); 

# keep data sorted by polygon order
map_data = arrange(map_data, order);

# plot map using ggplot2

p0 = ggplot(map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
     geom_polygon(aes(fill = cut_number(rate, 5))) +
     geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2) +
     scale_fill_brewer('Unemployment Rate (Jan 2011)', pal = 'PuRd') +
     coord_map();
#You may need to spell out the argument pal as pallete
```

Comment: @Ramnath: Awesome. I wonder how to show states names on this graph. Thanks

Comment: @Yaseen. One way to do it is `states = data.frame(state.center, state.abb)` followed by `p0 = p0 + geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 2)`

Comment: @Ramnath: Thanks a lot. It works fine. Thanks again for prompt reply.

Comment: If you're getting _ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’_, check this out: _http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765429/unable-to-install-r-package-in-ubuntu-11-04_

Comment: I'm having (at least) 2 problems. _Error: mapproj package required for this functionality.  Please install and try again._ Okay, did that. But then it's not clear which function _arrange_ is to be called. Is it from the _plyr_ package or from some other package? Has it been renamed? I tried _grid.arrange_ from _gridExtra_ package, but: _ map_data = grid.arrange(map_data, order);
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,_ If anyone knows the fix, please help. Cheers!

Comment: Note: The ggplot2 option _pal = 'PuRd'_ has become _palette = 'PuRd'_

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add Hawaii and Alaska to this map? For example for Hawaii I do:`map_data_hawaii <- map_data('world','Hawaii');
map_data_hawaii$region <- tolower(map_data_hawaii$region);
map_data_hawaii<- merge(unemp, map_data_hawaii, by = 'region')` So how can I plot this data over the US map? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Ramnath nailed this one.  If you're still looking for other solutions, there's a decent [example using other packages](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/2011/03/example-831-choropleth-maps.html) at the SAS-and-R blog.

Comment: I did see the same post yesterday at R-Blogger. Another option to look at.