# Unable to install R package in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: xml, r, ubuntu, installation

I'm new to Linux and R.

I installed R 2.12 in Ubuntu 11.04. Today I tried to install a new package, so I ran the following command:

```
install.packages('XML')
```

But the installation failed and gave the following information:

```
* installing *source* package ‘XML’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
No ability to remove finalizers on externalptr objects in this verison of R
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for xml2-config... no
Cannot find xml2-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘XML’
* removing ‘/home/spirit/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12/XML’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpoZYxnv/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
  installation of package 'XML' had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried:

```
sudo install.packages('XML')
```

But it gives the same error information.

Anyone can give me any advice?

Comment: Install `xml2-config`?

Comment: This question just helped me (again) in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I don't know about the question being off-topic or not, but the answer below also solved my problem with Ubuntu Trusty Tahr.

Comment: Should this be moved to the AskUbuntu stack? It is a question relating to using R or RStudio (though it probably occurs with other software?), caused by lack of required software packages in Ubuntu. It's a common enough question it seems according to the "Related" list I see at the right. And it could rightly be asked why are these packages missing from Ubuntu?

Comment: @rickHenderson It's also useful for other Linux distros.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

**The install.packages method**

You need to install the ubuntu package `libxml2-dev` So in a shell prompt type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

You will need special `sudo` powers for this.

**Ubuntu package method**

As Richie and Dirk mentioned, you can also use:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml
```

If you go down this path, I would recommend that you check out the [R ubuntu sources](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) page which will ensure you have a current version of R and the associated R packages. This could be important if you are using the LTS version of ubuntu.

Comment: Can you try synaptic? look for the package you need there

Comment: r-cran-xml is not enough, had to do libxml2-dev

Comment: Sharing my observation for a similar issue which might help MAC users. Even though i had all the dependent libraries i still got errors. After a lot a lot of trials this is what saved me- 
While installing via rstudio using install.packages(), you get a prompt asking -Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: 
Give your response here as 'n'. This worked for me.

Comment: In Debian stretch only `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` is enough to work

Comment: I am getting this error: sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml

Comment: Fedora users...: `dnf install libxml2-devel`

Answer (score 28):

The answer by Colin is correct in a narrow sense, but at the same time wrong as you can just say

```
 sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml
```

as XML is one of the CRAN packages available in Ubuntu. Do `apt-cache search r-cran-*` do see the others.