# Why can't I install the XML package

Tags: r, web

Am I making some basic error here?

```
install.packages("XML")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Program Files/R/R-2.13.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 2.13.0)
```

Comment: Such a question should be asked on stackoveflow, not here. But stop using R-2.13.0, it is deprecated.

Comment: You should probably upgrade to a more recent version of R. Actually from the look of it the most recent version of XML will probably work on your old R, but you may have to do it by hand.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765429/unable-to-install-r-package-in-ubuntu-11-04/7765470

Comment: Don't think that will help since OP is running windows.

Comment: Try downloading the binary for your OS [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html) and install it using `install.packages("path/to/where/you/downloaded/XML/binaries", type="source")`

Comment: Maybe you are missing libxml-2.0.

Comment: This worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035088/unable-to-install-r-package-due-to-xml-dependency-mismatch the `conda` way

Answer (score 5):

It is probably because [www.omegahat.org](http://www.omegahat.org) doesn't exist anymore. So,

command `install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")`
does not work. Instead use below:

```
install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be two conditions when you see such error:

1. The package does not exist in the library (you should install it
   from it's own library)
2. The package is not compatible with your R
   version (you should change your R version that is compatible, if you
   can afford it)

For the first condition, search on internet and read about the package you want to install and check the provider and repository (for this case, **XML**, it **is official R package**)

For the second condition, you can find the information in the following link:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html

you can check your R version by typing the following command into your R shell:

```
version
```

which will give you all the information, for e.g:

> ```
>            _
> ```
>
> platform       x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
>   arch           x86_64
>   os             darwin10.8.0
>   system         x86_64, darwin10.8.0
>   status
>   major          3
>   minor          0.1
>   year           2013
>   month          05
>   day            16
>   svn rev        62743
>   language       R
>   version.string R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
>   nickname       Good Sport

Answer (score 0):

First update the R-core:

```r
version
install.package('installr')
library(installr)
updateR()
```

Then install the XML module:

```r
install.packages("XML")
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me is downloading the old release of the XML package and installing from the package archive
install.packages("~/R/win-library/3.6/XML_3.99-0.3.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary").