# Unable to install XML package to Rstudio

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to install XML Package to Rstudio Using the ribbon: `Tools--> Install Packages --> Packages:` to type XML, but the dropdown list opend had only this packages : xml2, XML2R, xml2relational, xmlparsedata, xmlr, xmlrpc2.

Next, I tried:

```
install.packages("XML")
```

but received the warning:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘D:/BCDD/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

So I followed the link above :https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
and using these questions:

1. [Why can't I install the XML package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243974/why-cant-i-install-the-xml-package)
2. [Cannot install package XML to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042751/cannot-install-package-xml-to-r)

Then tried

`install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R",type="source")`

but received the same warning and more:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘D:/BCDD/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://www.omegahat.net/R/src/contrib/XML_3.99-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1547930 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package 'XML' ...
** using staged installation
Please define LIB_XML (and LIB_ZLIB, LIB_ICONV)
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'XML'
* removing 'D:/BCDD/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/XML'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\BCDD\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAhAYpl\downloaded_packages’
```

Any help to how to install the package XML will be appreciated

Comment: you need to install an older version of the package. The newest one is available only for R 4.0 or higher

Comment: in the links you posted it is suggested to use `install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R")` instead of `install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.net/R",type="source")` like you did

Comment: I tried without the: type="source" and received the first warning:  WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘D:/BCDD/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘XML’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the version you want from here: https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/XML/

According to their GitHub repo, version 3.99-0.3 should work for you, I can't try it out coz I have R4.0 and I can install only the most recent [3.99-0.5].

Alternatively, when you choose the version you want and run on your R console:

```
devtools::install_version("XML", version = "3.99-0.3") # or the version you want
```

Have a try. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [RStudio Support post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages)  which covers how to install older versions of packages.

Be sure to install rtools35 from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html)

Going to R 4.0.2 is not a particularly bad idea at this point.

Comment: Followed your advice and updated to R 4.0.2 and now XML package is available. Thank You!