# Using tryCatch and rvest to deal with 404 and other crawling errors

Tags: r, try-catch, rvest

When retrieving the h1 title using `rvest`, I sometimes run into 404 pages. This stop the process and returns this error.

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

See the example below

```
Data<-data.frame(Pages=c(
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html",
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omg-the-japanese-trump-commer.html",
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omar-mateen-posted-to-facebook.html",
"http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omar-mateen-posted-to-facdddebook.html"))
```

Code used to retrieve h1

```
library (rvest)
sapply(Data$Pages, function(url){
 url %>%
 as.character() %>% 
 read_html() %>% 
 html_nodes('h1') %>% 
 html_text()
 })
```

Is there a way to include an argument to ignore errors and continue the process ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for `try` or `tryCatch`, which are how R handles error catching.

With `try`, you just need to wrap the thing that might fail in `try()`, and it will return the error and keep running:

```
library(rvest)

sapply(Data$Pages, function(url){
  try(
    url %>%
      as.character() %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes('h1') %>% 
      html_text()
  )
})

# [1] "'Spam King' Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook scam messages"
# [2] "OMG, this Japanese Trump Commercial is everything"                                         
# [3] "Omar Mateen posted to Facebook during Orlando mass shooting"                               
# [4] "Error in open.connection(x, \"rb\") : HTTP error 404.\n"
```

However, while that will get everything, it will also insert bad data into our results. `tryCatch` allows you to configure what happens when an error is called by passing it a function to run when that condition arises:

```
sapply(Data$Pages, function(url){
  tryCatch(
    url %>%
      as.character() %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes('h1') %>% 
      html_text(), 
    error = function(e){NA}    # a function that returns NA regardless of what it's passed
  )
})

# [1] "'Spam King' Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook scam messages"
# [2] "OMG, this Japanese Trump Commercial is everything"                                         
# [3] "Omar Mateen posted to Facebook during Orlando mass shooting"                               
# [4] NA
```

There we go; much better.

---

#### Update

In the tidyverse, the `purrr` package offers two functions, `safely` and `possibly`, which work like `try` and `tryCatch`. They are *adverbs*, not verbs, meaning they take a function, modify it so as to handle errors, and return a new function (not a data object) which can then be called. Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

df <- Data %>% rowwise() %>%     # Evaluate each row (URL) separately
    mutate(Pages = as.character(Pages),    # Convert factors to character for read_html
           title = possibly(~.x %>% read_html() %>%    # Try to take a URL, read it,
                                html_nodes('h1') %>%    # select header nodes,
                                html_text(),    # and collect text inside.
                            NA)(Pages))    # If error, return NA. Call modified function on URLs.

df %>% select(title)
## Source: local data frame [4 x 1]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
## # A tibble: 4 × 1
##                                                                                        title
##                                                                                        <chr>
## 1 'Spam King' Sanford Wallace gets 2.5 years in prison for 27 million Facebook scam messages
## 2                                          OMG, this Japanese Trump Commercial is everything
## 3                                Omar Mateen posted to Facebook during Orlando mass shooting
## 4                                                                                       <NA>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see this Question for explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

```
urls<-c(
    "http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/spam-king-sanford-wallace.html",
    "http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omg-the-japanese-trump-commer.html",
    "http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omar-mateen-posted-to-facebook.html",
    "http://boingboing.net/2016/06/16/omar-mateen-posted-to-facdddebook.html")


readUrl <- function(url) {
    out <- tryCatch(
        {
            message("This is the 'try' part")
            url %>% as.character() %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('h1') %>% html_text() 
        },
        error=function(cond) {
            message(paste("URL does not seem to exist:", url))
            message("Here's the original error message:")
            message(cond)
            return(NA)
        }
        }
    )    
    return(out)
}

y <- lapply(urls, readUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one simple solution, that i found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094157/handling-error-response-to-empty-webpage-from-read-html):

```
tryCatch(read_html('http://tweg.com'), 
         error = function(e){'empty page'})    # just return "empty page"
#> [1] "empty page"
```

And it works for me perfectly.

Also i use it like this:

```
page <- NULL
url <- 'http://tweg.com'
tryCatch(page <- read_html(url), 
         error = function(e){'empty page'})

if (is.null(page) == FALSE) {
 #block of code
}
```