# Skip the error and go through with the loop to get the output

Tags: r

When I am trying to run below code I get an error as                                                               "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class ""try-error"" to a data.frame "

I am using try function to skip through the LINKS which are not working and continue with the loop but that's not happening. Can someone help me with this

```
base_url <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1409916/000162828017002570/exhibit211nobilishealthcor.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1300317/000119312507128181/dex211.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1453814/000145381417000063/subsidiariesoftheregistran.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/25743/000138713117001111/ex21-1.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/880631/000119312517065534/d280058dex211.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1058290/000105829017000008/ctshexhibit21112312016.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1031927/000141588916005383/ex21-1.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1358071/000135807118000008/cxoexhibit211.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/904979/000090497918000006/exhibit211q4fy17listofsubs.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/41296/000094420901500099/dex21.txt",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/808461/000080846117000024/gciexhibit21-1123116.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1101026/000107878213000519/f10k123112_ex21.htm",
              "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/932372/000141588915000759/ex21-1.htm"
              )

  df <- lapply(base_url,function(u){
  try({

  html_obj <- read_html(u)
  draft_table <- html_nodes(html_obj,'table')
  cik <- substr(u,start = 41,stop = 47)
  draft1 <- html_table(draft_table,fill = TRUE)
  final <- c(cik,draft1)
  },silent = TRUE)
})


require(reshape2)
data <- melt(df)
data <- as.data.frame(data,row.names = NULL)
data <- data[,1:2]
names(data) <- c("CIK","Company")

data2 <- transform(data, CIK = na.locf(CIK ))
```

Comment: try with `tryCatch` and on error, return for example an empty data frame or null. Also your `melt` will not work, you have to `dplyr::bind_rows()` first I guess.

Comment: can you help me with the code ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112113/1527403

Answer (score 1):

You could use purrr's `safely` function. It creates for each url a list containing the results from the below function and the error message if such exists without exiting the loop.

```
library(tidyverse)

checklinks <- function(url) {
  cik <- url %>% 
    str_extract("[:digit:]+")
  table <- read_html(url) %>% 
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table() %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% 
    na_if("") %>% 
    filter(rowMeans(is.na(.)) < 1) %>% 
    mutate(cik = cik) %>% 
    select(cik, everything())
  return(table)
}

final <- base_url %>% 
  map(safely(checklinks)) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  .$result %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: After getting the output in 'links_t', how should i get the ouput into a dataframe ? because if i use the below code it throws error: 
require(reshape2)
data <- melt(df)
data <- as.data.frame(links_t,row.names = NULL)

Comment: i want to get the output in a dataframe

Comment: Can you please help me to get the data into a dataframe ?

Comment: I've edited the above code to help you get the data into a dataframe. However, its not an easy task considering the sites you provide. It's a mixture of different tables and one is even a txt file.

The above code works for all but two urls

Answer (score 0):

`try` will not let you skip, but rather return an error of class `try-error` if there is a problem.

so afterwards, you could still add something like:

```
check <- sapply(df, class) != "try-error"
df <- df[check]
```

or use `tryCatch` directly:

```
df <- lapply(base_url, function(u) {
  tryCatch({
    html_obj <- read_html(u)
    draft_table <- html_nodes(html_obj,'table')
    cik <- substr(u,start = 41,stop = 47)
    draft1 <- html_table(draft_table,fill = TRUE)
    final <- c(cik,draft1)
  }, error = function(x) NULL)
})
```

Comment: Is there any other way I can do this.I wanted to continue with the loop to scrape data from site rather throwing error and the loop stops. ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, like this no error should be thrown and the loop should continue. I add an alternative with `tryCatch`, but like that you still have the `NULLs` that you may need to remove depending on how you want to continue

Comment: It is throwing an error :                                                                        
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: where exactly now? how have you modified your code thus far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
for(i in something)
{
  res <- try(expression_to_get_data)
  if(inherits(res, "try-error"))
  {
    #error handling code, maybe just skip this iteration using
    continue
  }
  #rest of iteration for case of no error
}
```

[Source of solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852406/r-script-how-to-continue-code-execution-on-error)