# How do I check the html status code when calling xml_read using the xml2 package in R?

Tags: r, xml-parsing, xml2

**TL;DR**: See title

**Details:**

I'm currently querying an XML API that's a little quirky.

Sometimes when you make a request, you get back an XML file of the data requested. Other times, you get back an XML file with a message that says your request has been queued.

I've thought about using xpath queries to see if the data I'm expecting is there before continuing on, but it's entirely possible that a valid, properly served query will result in an empty set so this will sometimes yield a false negative.

One saving grace is that the server will return a different HTTP status code when it is queueing the request. However, I don't know how to inspect the result of `xml_read` to tell what the code is and the documentation does not seem to provide any guidance.

Comment: so…use `httr::GET()` and test for status vs use `xml2::read_xml()`. I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't know you couldn't do that after read_xml call... *feels dumb*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help. The idea is to get the document and check the response code, then provide the document to the XML api [How to determine if a url object in R base package returns '404 Not Found'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139357/how-to-determine-if-a-url-object-in-r-base-package-returns-404-not-found) . BTW, did you mean `read_xml` from `xml2` package or some other package?

Comment: Using xml2.

I had thought of that, actually, but I had trouble using read_xml on what the GET function returned. I'll dig into that, I guess.

Comment: ??httr:quickstart will show you the basics. Sonething like, get a response object with r <- GET('yoururl'). This is a structured object -- not just text. You can then access the parts with status(r) to check the status, and content(r) to get the text that you will pass to read_xml

Comment: That doesn't actually work. When you try to pass the result of `content` to `read_xml` you get `no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument')"` However, if you call `read_xml(r$content)` this works.