# For loop - doesn't work properly

Tags: json, r, for-loop

I'm trying to use Indeed API to search for specific jobs and I faced a problem when for loop doesn't go through each iterations.
    Here is the example of code that I used:

```
original_url_1 <- "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=750330686195873&format=json&q="
original_url_2 <-"&l=Canada&sort=date&radius=10&st=&jt=&start=0&limit=25&fromage=3&filter=&latlong=1&co=ca&chnl=&userip=69.46.99.196&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2" 
keywords <- c("data+scientist", "data+analyst")

for(i in keywords) { 
    url <- paste0(original_url_1,i,original_url_2)
    x <- as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(httr::GET(url),
                                    as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")))
     data <- rbind(data, x)
 }
```

Url leads to JSON file and adding one of the keyword to the url will change the JSON file. So I'm trying to repeat this for all keywords and store the result in the dataframe. However, when I'm trying to use more  keywords I'm getting the result only for a few first keywords.

Comment: Minor issue: `url <- paste0(original_url,"/",i)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just modified my answer to show original urls - I'm actually inserting those keywords in the middle of url.

Comment: be careful of the names. I edited the code appropriately...

Comment: also you need to initialize object _before_ using them into a loop. I am posting an answer for that reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code:

```
original_url_1 <- "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=750330686195873&format=json&q="
original_url_2 <-"&l=Canada&sort=date&radius=10&st=&jt=&start=0&limit=25&fromage=3&filter=&latlong=1&co=ca&chnl=&userip=69.46.99.196&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2" 
keywords <- c("data+scientist", "data+analyst")

data <- data.frame()

for (i in keywords) {
  tryCatch({url <- paste0(original_url_1,i,original_url_2)
  x <- as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(httr::GET(url),
                                                     as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")))
  data <- rbind(data, x)
  }, error = function(t){})
}
```

Comment: No closing bracket `for (i in keywords){`

Comment: It was there, just not highlighted as a code - so the closing bracket was under the code. Thanks for pointing this out. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
 original_url_1 <- "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=750330686195873&format=json&q="
 original_url_2 <-"&l=Canada&sort=date&radius=10&st=&jt=&start=0&limit=25&fromage=3&filter=&latlong=1&co=ca&chnl=&userip=69.46.99.196&useragent=Mozilla/%2F4.0%28Firefox%29&v=2" 
 keywords <- c("data_scientist", "data+analyst")

 data<-data.table(NULL)#initialization of object

 for(i in keywords) { 
   url <- paste0(Original_url_1,i,Original_url_2)
   x <- as.data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(httr::GET(url),as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")))
   data <- rbind(data, x)
}

>dim(data)
[1] 39 31
```

Comment: thanks again! I really appreciate your help. I did specify the object at my code, just forgot to add it to the answer!
As I am getting some results I think that the problem is with a loop itself, it just doesn’t want to do the iteration for all keywords – it just stops at some point.
I was just thinking that the problem could be that when the certain keywords don’t show any results it will just throw an error and the loop will stop. I probably just need to add an IF statement and try again. What do you think?

Comment: Or it might be the API that does not let like many requests. Try `sleep()` in order to pause the loop after N times. Concerning your comment above, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139357/how-to-determine-if-a-url-object-in-r-base-package-returns-404-not-found

Comment: Just rerun the code using tryCatch() function and it works! So the problem was that the loop stops if the error occur. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: you might want to edi the answer adequately, incorporating the changes you made...