# Error when installing swirl in RStudio 3.1.2

Tags: r, package

Hey I tried installing swirl running the following command:

```
install.packages("swirl")
```

I got the following error:

```
    ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR -------------------------      --
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/franco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘RCurl’ ...
** package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for curl-config... no
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/franco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/franco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘RCurl’ are not available for package       ‘swirl’
* removing ‘/home/franco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/swirl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp7G87EM/downloaded_packages’
```

I tried installing "curl" and "RCurl" packages but I got the same error messages. I don't know how to change the path as directed in the ANTICONF ERROR.

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 and R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages('swirl', dependencies = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` ?

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765429/unable-to-install-r-package-in-ubuntu-11-04/7765470

Comment: @DavidMaust `apt-get install libcurl14-openssl-dev` did it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this answer for the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44230727/13626355

Answer (score 3):

now it's

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated as on 30-05-2019:
I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I got this while installing the packages-
Using PKG_CFLAGS=

> ------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
>
> Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:  *
>   deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)  * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora,
>   CentOS, RHEL)  * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)  * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac
>   OSX) If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in
>   your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If
>   pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually
>   via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
>
> ---

I used the command in terminal >

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

And then it worked fine.