# R/ RStudio - install devtools fails?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I am trying to install `devtools` in my RStudio. But I get tons of errors:

```
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lssl -lcrypto
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘git2r’ ...
** package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for library containing inflate... -lz
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libssl... no
configure: WARNING: "pkg-config failed to find libssl."
checking for library containing EVP_EncryptInit... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpWzaIce/R.INSTALL67fa335a4d20/git2r':
configure: error: 
  ---------------------------------------------
   The OpenSSL library that is required to
   build git2r was not found.

   Please install:
     libssl-dev    (package on e.g. Debian and Ubuntu)
     openssl-devel (package on e.g. Fedora, CentOS and RHEL)
     openssl       (Homebrew package on OS X)
   and try again.

   If the OpenSSL library is installed on
   your system but the git2r configuration
   is unable to find it, you can specify
   the include and lib path to OpenSSL with:
   R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-libssl-include=INCLUDE_PATH --with-libssl-lib=LIB_PATH' git2r
  ---------------------------------------------
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
* removing ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/git2r’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpzxXdFr/downloaded_packages’
```

So I tried to install `libcurl`:

```
> install.packages("libcurl")
Installing package into ‘/home/lau/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘libcurl’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)
> install.packages("curl")
```

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04. And R 3.4.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

Comment: @akrun thank you. it works now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error messages may be a bit confusing, because RStudio is asking you to install libcurl and openssl libraries for your Linux OS; for those you actually need Ubuntu packages instead of R packages.

Open a command line terminal, and type

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Once the installation of your Ubuntu packages is completed, try again and you'll be able to install the devtools R package

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04. You **do not need** to close and reopen RStudio for it to work.

Comment: Does not work for Ubuntu 18.04 - libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1) but 1.1.0h-2.0+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: I also needed to include `libxml2-dev` in the above to make devtools install.

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains the answer:-

```
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Message: 
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'

Executed this command:

> rpm -qa|grep curl

Result

```
python-pycurl-7.19.0-19.el7.x86_64  
curl-7.29.0-42.el7_4.1.x86_64  
libcurl-7.29.0-42.el7_4.1.x86_64  
-->libcurl-devel-7.29.0-42.el7_4.1.x86_64  <---this entry was missing
```

Executed this command

> yum install libcurl-devel

problem solved.

Comment: This answer would be easier to read with some code formatting

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me on **Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS** using **R version 3.6.1**

My guess is this might have something to do with `Anaconda3`...

What worked for me is:

```
conda install -c r r-devtools
```

Then in `R`

```
install.packages("rlang")
install.packages("devtools")
```

I should mention that conda as a package manager for R works great but you should stick to conda as much as you can, *i.e.* DON'T INSTALL PACKAGES IN `R`, BUT WITH CONDA (unless there is not a recipe for that package) using either `conda-forge`, `bioconda`, and `defaults` channels (open-source channels); being careful not to mix with proprietary channels (*e.g.* `anaconda`, `r`).

When you need packages that are not available in the channel set you are using, you must install them by hand into an external location outside of the conda environment. For example, `.libPaths()` shows I have two libraries:

- `/home/tsundoku/anaconda3/lib/R/library` # where anaconda packages are stored
- `/usr/lib/R/library` # where I store packages in external location

For a good read on managing `.libPaths()` see [@MilesMcBain](https://twitter.com/MilesMcBain)'s [blog-post here](https://milesmcbain.xyz/hacking-r-library-paths/)