# R: Cannot install rJava; what is r-api-3.4?

Tags: java, r, package, installation, rjava

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with R version 3.5.1, installed following [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/). I am trying to install the CRAN package **rJava**, which I do the following way (as seen [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858961/install-rjava-on-ubuntu-failed)):

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

However, I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rjava : Depends: r-api-3.4
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But when I try:

```
sudo apt-get install r-api-3.4
```

I get:

```
E: Package 'r-api-3.4' has no installation candidate
```

How to overcome this problem with `r-api-3.4`? Basically, I need to install `rJava` to be able to install and use `XLConnect`... In Ubuntu 16.04, I had no problems whatsoever...

**EDIT:**

Apparently, `r-api-3.4` should be provided by `r-base-core`. I do have `r-base-core` installed in its newest version, why do I still see errors then?

Comment: why not go through the R console to install packages?

Comment: I tried that first, but it gave errors, then I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765429/unable-to-install-r-package-in-ubuntu-11-04 , https://askubuntu.com/questions/858961/install-rjava-on-ubuntu-failed , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing

Comment: and https://askubuntu.com/questions/176115/what-is-the-best-way-of-installing-the-r-package-xlconnect

Comment: Basically, I need `rJava` to be able to use `XLConnect`... In Ubuntu 16.04 I had no problems

Comment: That produces the exact same output `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rjava : Depends: r-api-3.4
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: might be because those have not been created for >= R-3.5?

Comment: Then how to overcome that?

Comment: Apparently `r-api-3.4` should be provided by `r-base-core`... why am I seeing this errors then?

Comment: maybe its because u r using R-3.5.1

Comment: So what should be the way to get rJava to work with R-3.5.1?

Comment: check out this thread: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2018-May/002832.html. you might want to use R-3.4 for now

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The API versions are provided by `r-base-core`. The reason is that binary packages (sometimes) depend on the R version, for which they have been build. This way you can only install packages that fit together.

In your case you have packages from the main Ubuntu repository (`r-base-core` 3.4.x providing `r-api-3.4` and `r-cran-rjava` requiring `r-api-3.4`) and from a custom PPA (`r-base-core`  3.5.y providing `r-api-3.5`). One option would be to only use the version from Ubuntu, i.e. R 3.4. Another solution is to add an additional PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u3.5
sudo apt-get update
```

After that a version of `r-cran-rjava` requiring `r-api-3.5` should be available.
See also http://rubuntu.netlify.com/post/2018-05-25-announcing-c2d4u3-5/ and http://rubuntu.netlify.com/post/2018-06-11-r-3.5-on-debian-and-ubuntu-update/.

Finally, you always have the possibility to install the R packages directly from CRAN. That is currently the only possibility when you are using the [CRAN supplied R backports on Debian](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/).

Comment: thanks for the answer! I guess I will stick to R 3.4 for now

Comment: I didn't like the going back to 3.4 version as I would have to reinstall all the other packages, and didn't understand any of the links given in this answer. I have r 3.5 and adding the addition PPA mentioned helped. Along with the [main instructions here for installing rjava](https://github.com/hannarud/r-best-practices/wiki/Installing-RJava-(Ubuntu)) and restarting R. My installation procedure is [here](http://agent18.github.io/R-installation.html) and my installation of packages is documented [here](http://agent18.github.io/learning-R.html) , search for packages.

Comment: After installing the ppa (thanks for that!) I also found it necessary to update libquantlib: `sudo apt install libquantlib0*`

Comment: This link was also helpful: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/