# Create a heatmap of USA with state abbreviations and characteristic frequency in R

Tags: r, dictionary, heatmap

I would like to create a map of the USA (perhaps a heatmap) to show frequency of a certain characteristic among states. I am not sure of what package to use or if my data is in the proper form. My data is in the table tf

```
tf
 AB  AK  AL  AN  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  EN  FL  GA  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS 
  1  21  31   1  12  56 316  53  31  16   7   1 335  63  11  42  29  73  40  2
```

For the most part, my abbreviations are US (aside from a few Canadian instances). What is the best suggested approach for graphically displaying this on a map?

Now how do I get granularity of less than 50 per color?

[image]

Comment: [Maptools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/index.html) (`?maptools`) and [maps](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maps/index.html) (`?maps`) will be a nice starting point. You may also find the [spatial task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [State level unemployment in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385713/state-level-unemployment-in-r)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

two packages:
maps, ggplot2.
There is an excellent example at:
?map_data()

just to start with:

```
tf= structure(list(state = structure(1:14, .Label = c("AK", "AL", 
"AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "IA", "IL", "IN", 
"KS"), class = "factor"), num = c(21L, 31L, 12L, 56L, 316L, 53L, 
31L, 7L, 335L, 63L, 42L, 73L, 40L, 2L), region = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 14L), .Label = c("alabama", 
"alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", 
"delaware", "florida", "georgia", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", 
"kansas"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("state", "num", "region"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))

require(maps);require(ggplot2)

states <- map_data("state")
tfmerged <- merge(states, tf, sort = FALSE, by = "region")
tfmerged <- tfmerged[order(tfmerged$order), ]
qplot(long, lat, data = tfmerged, group = group, fill = num,
geom="polygon")
```

Then fill the rests of the states info.

Comment: Would I just want to append an L to my numeric data then?

Comment: @megv, no need to append an L, i just added that to show the data I used. What you might need to add is the name of the states so it matches with the states$region so the merge can work.

Comment: Since I already have a table with state abbreviation and counts can can i just insert that directly into the structure. Sorry..I am a bit new to this.

Comment: What you need is to make sure there is at least one key (a variable that matches in both datasets) when you are doing the merge. So if you want to keep the state abreviation I guess you would need to rename region or create a variable in states with that info.

Comment: Also..what is the region pertain to in the structure?

Comment: How would I change my color scale to include more bins..right now it every change of 50

Comment: Can you add an image of the result?

Comment: I added the image..now how do I get it broken up to finer granularity than 50?

Comment: This is complicated. You are actually drawing each and every state. when map package already has one build in. The simplest solution is to plot using maptools and just color the states

Answer (score 8):

Another approach with `spplot`:

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(sp)
```

First read the data and add a column with the names of the states:

```
txt <- "AB  AK  AL  AN  AR  AZ  CA  CO  CT  DC  DE  EN  FL  GA  HI  IA  ID  IL  IN  KS
    1  21  31   1  12  56 316  53  31  16   7   1 335  63  11  42  29  73  40  2"

dat <- stack(read.table(text = txt,  header = TRUE))
names(dat)[2] <-'state.abb'
dat$states <- tolower(state.name[match(dat$state.abb,  state.abb)])
```

Then you get the map and convert it to a `SpatialPolygons`:

```
mapUSA <- map('state',  fill = TRUE,  plot = FALSE)
nms <- sapply(strsplit(mapUSA$names,  ':'),  function(x)x[1])
USApolygons <- map2SpatialPolygons(mapUSA,  IDs = nms,  CRS('+proj=longlat'))
```

And now you add the information from your data:

```
idx <- match(unique(nms),  dat$states)
dat2 <- data.frame(value = dat$value[idx], state = unique(nms))
row.names(dat2) <- unique(nms)

USAsp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(USApolygons,  data = dat2)
```

Finally you plot it:

```
spplot(USAsp['value'])
```

Added image[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of the result?

Comment: Is there a method to add Hawaii and Alaska to this map?

Comment: Yes, but you have to use a different map. For example, `mapUSA <- map('world2', 'USA', fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)`.