# Heatmap in R including Alaska and Hawaii

Tags: r, maps, r-maptools

I would like to create a heat-map including both Alaska and Hawaii in R. This is a reference, but it does not include Hawaii or Alaska:

[Create a heatmap of USA with state abbreviations and characteristic frequency in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537727/create-a-heatmap-of-usa-with-state-abbreviations-and-characteristic-frequency-in)

Comment: Try albersusa package
https://rud.is/b/2016/03/29/easier-composite-u-s-choropleths-with-albersusa/

Answer (score 1):

The map you're talking about is often called a **choropleth** or a **thematic map**, not a heatmap. While the definition isn't completely rigid, choropleths show difference on delineated levels, such as countries, regions or states, while heatmaps tend to be a continuous overlay which does not link directly to political boundaries (such as a map that colours an image of the US by pixel rather than by state, perhaps modelling air pressure, or the like).

The package `choroplethr` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/choroplethr.pdf) uses the `USAChoropleth` object bundled to draw a map of the US that has Hawaii and Alaska as insets.

An example from the `choroplethr` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/b-state-choropleth.html)

[image: An example from the choroplethr vignette]

If you want to manually locate Hawaii or Alaska, and are familiar with `ggplot2`, see the answer [Relocating Alaska and Hawaii on thematic map of the USA with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757771/relocating-alaska-and-hawaii-on-thematic-map-of-the-usa-with-ggplot2) .

Comment: Would have benefited from a working demonstration: vignette link is no longer valid.